# W2K3 CA server gone offline, how to clean my AD?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2003, certificate-authority

We have decommissioned an old W2K3 DC server, on which was a CA installed.
The CA wasn't really used (no PKI infrastructure), just was here as a test.

After the server 's gone offline, I have several CertificateServicesClient-AutoEnrollment, EventID 6 on other servers (the RPC server is not available). I cannot make this W2K3 server online anymore, so what would be the best solution :

- Clean my AD records to make other machines understand that there is no more any CA  (following https://mssec.wordpress.com/2013/03/19/manually-remove-old-ca-references-in-active-directory/ and/or part https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555151) ?
- Create a CA with the same name (simply "certs") on one of our W2K8 servers ?

I'm slightly nervous about how to solve this problem, because I don't want to break anything ...

Thanks a lot for your help.